# iOS - Loading custom table cell results in error on second load

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am working on an iPad app with a table view with standard cells, when a custom cell is selected, it should expand and load a custom nib file. This it does fine, for the first selection.

If I select a standard cell it loads the nib fine and if I select it again it goes back to normal, upon the second loading, it throws a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error (I don't think I will ever get xcodes errors, seem to be the most abstract).

My code is below and the line is when it dequeues the cell for reuse, 3rd line:

```
if([listCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"open") {
        NSLog(@"Loading open cell at %i", indexPath.row);
        CustomMessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomMessageCell"];
        //Loads the nib file and grabs the last object, presumably the table cell, as it is the only object in the file.
        if(cell==nil) {
            cell = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomMessageCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject] autorelease];
        }
        UILabel *message = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
        UIButton *approve = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
        message.text = @"Test";
        return cell;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you compiled and run on a real device? Sometimes you get more info then running just on the simulation.

Also other things to check:

- you should check that the Identifier of the Nib file in IB is set
  correctly to CustomMessageCell.
- Be sure that your subviews identifiers in IB are set correctly.
- Note that you should not autorelease the cell as it is already autoreleased as returned by the lastObject method. This could cause another reason for crash.

Try also running your app (on a real device) and profile it using the Zombies and then Leaks profiling tools. (Instead of just "Run" choose "Profile").

Hope this helps.

Comment: It has been tested on an iPad 2, the identifier is correct and the issue only seems to occur on the second clicking of a cell, it loads fine first time.
I will take a look at the zombies profile and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't `autorelease` cell in this line:

```
cell = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomMessageCell" 
                                 owner:self options:nil] lastObject] autorelease];
```

Just create like this:

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomMessageCell" 
                               owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
```

Comment: Thanks, but even removing that causes the issue. I added it, assuming it was a memory issue. Guessing it isn't?

Comment: You're not calling alloc, or retain, so you shouldn't autorelease.